# Lower bound on Carmichael Function

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

What is the tightest lower bound currently known for the Carmichael function?

I imagine it must grow much more slowly than the Euler's totient function which according to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301837/is-the-euler-phi-function-bounded-below) is bounded as

$$ \phi(n) \ge \frac{n}{e^{\gamma} \log \log n+ \frac{3}{\log \log n}} $$

But searching around on Google it's hard to find any literature on lower bounds of the carmichael function

Comment: Probably better to search around on MathSciNet, if you have access.

Comment: sadly I do not have access to MathSciNet :(

Comment: Have you come across Erdős, Paul; Pomerance, Carl; Schmutz, Eric (1991). "Carmichael's lambda function". Acta Arithmetica. 58 (4): 363–385. MR 1121092. Zbl 0734.11047 and Sándor, Jozsef; Crstici, Borislav (2004). Handbook of number theory II. Dordrecht: Kluwer Academic. pp. 32–36, 193–195. ISBN 978-1-4020-2546-4. Zbl 1079.11001?

Comment: i have not come across that but i went to a certain source of articles, and looked for anything written by carl pomerance with carmichael in its title and I found an article titled "period of the power generator" by him which yielded a lower bound :). Thank you for inspiring the search!

Comment: Erdos' papers are collected at https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/Erdos.html (although for some reason, the collection stops at 1989, so Erdos-Pomerance-Schmutz isn't there). The paper is available on Pomerance's website, https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/ (and I think Acta Arithmetica has made most of its issues freely available on its website). But maybe you could write up what you found in the "period of the power generator" paper, and post it as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An answer is given in Theorem 1 of the paper *[Carmichael's lambda function](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/lambda.pdf)*, by Erdos, Pomerance, and Schmutz.

**Theorem $1$**: For every $c < 1/\log{2}$, we have $\lambda(n) > (\log{n})^{c \log\log\log{n}}$ for all large enough $n$. On the other hand, for some constant $c'$, and infinitely many $n$, we also have $\lambda(n) < (\log{n})^{c'
 \log\log\log{n}}$.

Comment: Paper link: https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-00-01282-5

Comment: I deleted my answer after noting your answer

Comment: I gave a direct link to the paper on Carl Pomerance's website in an earlier comment.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more careful - I should have noticed that the link in the above comment is to a different paper. Just in case something happens to the link on Carl Pomerance's website, here are also [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20190421183347/https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/lambda.pdf) and [eudml](https://eudml.org/doc/206359) link.